# why ajax restful client does not shows data(java)?

Tags: java, json, ajax, rest

i create a html form , when i press the button it should show me the only user i have in json in alert box,but it just shows an empty json body.i checked the rest class it works fine.and url in ajax is true.

//pojo

```
package PackOne;

public class User {

    String name;
    String pass;


    public User(){}
    public User(String name,String pass){
        this.name=name;
        this.pass=pass;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getPass() {
        return pass;
    }

    public void setPass(String pass) {
        this.pass = pass;
    }

}
```

> Blockquote

//here is rest class

```
@Path("/users")
public class Rest {

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public User getDefaultUserInJSON() {
        System.out.println("i am in rest!");
        User user=new User("plpl","333");
        System.out.println("new user created!");
        return user;
    }

}
```

//this is html,when i press the button it should show the only user a have in json form but it just alert me an empty json body

> Blockquote

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Add or delete contact</title>
</head>
<body>

    <button id="ajax">ajax call</button>
    <script src="js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $('#ajax').click(function() {
            alert("click!");
            $.ajax({
                type : "GET",
                dataType : "json",
                url : "http://localhost:8080/ProjectB/rest/users",
                success : function(data) {
                    alert(data);
                }
            });
            return false;
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Does your system log message print out? e.g. `i am in rest!`

Comment: You are returning `user` from your backend... does that serialize as JSON? if not, that is likely where your error is. The browser is expecting JSON.

Answer (score 0):

this all works,i didn't use alert correctly in html.

```
alert(data.name);
alert(data.pass);
```

cause function(data) returns me a user object.but i'm not sure yet,should not it return me a json object?